# How to pass the actual barcode scanned to an ImageView

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

I've an activity in my app which **Either** picks an image from gallery to scan for a barcode and then displays the result in a `TextView` and picked image in an `ImageView` **OR** starts the camera to scan one and displays the result in the respective `TextView`.

I'm using [Google Mobile Vision API](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) (indirectly through a [Library](https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner) just to skip the boiler plate code) and the scanning works impressively fast.

I've tried my best to find a way before asking this question through searching the sample project of the library and Google Mobile Vision API and the internet but failed to find one.

How can I pass the actual scanned barcode to an `ImageView` (or an Activity)? (seems impossible directly)

My code is basically this (just with some intents etc)

```
@Override
    public void onRetrieved(final Barcode barcode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Barcode read: " + barcode.displayValue);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("code retrieved")
                        .setMessage(barcode.displayValue);
                builder.show();
            }
        });


    }

    // for multiple callback
    @Override
    public void onRetrievedMultiple(final Barcode closetToClick, final List<BarcodeGraphic> barcodeGraphics) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String message = "Code selected : " + closetToClick.displayValue + "\n\nother " +
                        "codes in frame include : \n";
                for (int index = 0; index < barcodeGraphics.size(); index++) {
                    Barcode barcode = barcodeGraphics.get(index).getBarcode();
                    message += (index + 1) + ". " + barcode.displayValue + "\n";
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("code retrieved")
                        .setMessage(message);
                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++) {
        Barcode barcode = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
        Log.e("value", barcode.displayValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetrievedFailed(String reason) {
        // in case of failure
    }
}
```

Above code works great but is there a way possible to use that `SparseArray` for obtaining the actual scanned barcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library to generate `Bitmap` from barcode value.
Add gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

Then use the next code:

```
public void generateBarcode(Barcode barcode) {

    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

    String barcodeNumber = barcode.displayValue;
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(barcodeNumber, BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, 200, 200);
        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hardiksharma, but `Google Vision API` doesn't provide way to generate barcode image

Comment: I admit my silly mistake, yes, I'm using a library based on Zxing library for generating barcodes but here, I don't want to regenerate a QR/Bar code instead I want to take a snap/picture of the barcode and want to display it in an ImageView. And Do note that a QR/bar code is different than a picture of QR/bar code as the picture contains real world objects (a paper or a book or whatever on which the code is printed). Get My point?